# Why do images look resized on my GitHub wiki?

Tags: github

If you take a look at my [README](https://github.com/kiryha/Eve) file on GitHub (the wiki pages have the same issue) and compare screenshots with the original images ([Clone Repo](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48019681856_fd0a55facb_o.gif) and [Project Manager](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48019770601_10f9642217_o.gif)) you will see that images on GitHub look bad, like there were scaled.

Even if I set the proper image size with `<img src="https://your-image-url.type" width="100" height="100">` the situation is the same.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with GitHub. The images are hosted on `live.staticflickr.com` and look the same if you load directly from that URL. This is happening somewhere else in your pipeline. Why are you hotlinking to Flickr in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean "look the same"?

I made a screen from the GitHub page and put the original image on top to demonstrate the difference:
https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48020804711_dc38bc313c_o.gif

Obviously, the image on GitHub is scaled down.

Comment: I am placing my images to Flicker cos I don't need them in my repo.

Comment: I mean "look the same" in the sense that, as far as I can tell, GitHub isn't doing anything at all to your images. They look the way they do because that's what you put on Flickr. "cos I don't need them in my repo"—I disagree. You're embedding them in your README. They should be included in your repo. Does it really make sense for somebody with a local clone to have to make a network request to Flickr just to consume your README?

Comment: Ok, I can include images from README in the repo, make sense.
But the wiki has the same issue, and I don't need wiki images in the repo, cos wiki is a separate repository.

I still can`t understand why you saying "look the same" when you can see from the screenshot that it scaled down quite noticeable.

Comment: And if I place the image to the repository, it behaves the same.

Comment: On my machine they look exactly the same, and I don't see any reason this would be different for you. The scaling may be happening on _Flickr_, but it's not happening on GitHub. Compare [this version](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48019681856_fd0a55facb_o.gif) that I get clicking on your image and [this version](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4f53ef035aad396e6e8459ac64fa602cba118e6c/68747470733a2f2f6c6976652e737461746963666c69636b722e636f6d2f36353533352f34383031393638313835365f666430613535666163625f6f2e676966) that I get with "view image".

Comment: Maybe your _browser_ is scaling something? Try resetting your zoom with Ctrl+0.

Comment: This was the issue, my browser was not set to 100% display scale! Thanks, Chris!